# Add scroll view to storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, scroll

I have a storyboard project where a view controller pushing a  nav controller which is in turn pushing more view controllers.

so its view controller >> nav controller >> view controllers

How would I add a scroll view to those view controllers being pushed by the nav controller? I'm used to the .m and .h where you create a UIScrollView IBOutlet and change the size in the .m.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view controller in your storyboard file, you can add a UIScrollView to it and connect it to an outlet defined in code. You just have to remember to zoom in when you're editing your storyboard file, because not all zoom levels allow you to add all the available UI objects.

Comment: Did this but when app is launched it only displays what can fit on the screen and I can't scroll down.

Comment: Did you change the scroll view's content size after loading it from the storyboard?

Comment: i got it to work the problem was the start size vs content size